Desire (たい or ほしい) for adjectives
I was just wondering how to express a desire for an adjective.
e.g. I want to be strong.
For verbs I learned the common approach is using the たい-form while for nouns it would be using ほしい.
Neither of these seems applicable for an adjective like 強い.
Using a translator I got
強くなりたい。
This works, I guess but I am still wondering if this is a good general approach or even natural-sounding Japanese.
Also I am wondering if there is a difference regarding this topic, between i- and na-adjectives. I read in a few sources that na-adjectives stem from nouns historically and are as such, grammatically pretty similar to them (and rather different from i-adjectives).
So I am wondering if something like this would be correct:
有名がほしい。(I want to be famous.)

Besides "wanting to become ..." as described in jarmanso7's answer, 〜たい can be also used directly with adjectival copulae: here about na-adjectives + でありたい (である is formal form of copula, and だ is its contraction), here about i-adjectives in 〜く form + ありたい (about this, I remind that some forms of i-adjectives are contractions of 〜く + some form of ある, e.g. 〜く + あった → 〜かった).

The problem here is actually one that exists in English as well - you CANNOT "want" an adjective, you can only "want" a verb or a noun.
More specifically, you cannot want strong, but you have to want to be strong, or want to become strong, or want to be made strong. You see, not adding a verb between want and strong would make a sentence sound funny to a native English speaker, and also grammatically incorrect.
If you think about it, an adjective is not an action, and you cannot want it. You cannot want strong, or want hot, you can only want to be strong or want something else to become hot. Missing a verb is not just ungrammatical, but also illogical.
The same goes for Japanese, 強い or 暑い are just descriptions, you cannot want them, but you can only want to become them (強くなりたい) or you want something else to become them (今年の夏がもっと暑くなってほしい). Or, you can want something to be made into more of them(passive voice) (コーヒーをもっと熱くしてほしいね). The verb is actually the conveyor of the main action here, and is just as important as the adjective.
Grammatically, there is no way of turning adjectives into a "want" mode on their own, and a verb is required, aka -たい and -てほしい only exists for verbs, and 有名がほしい doesn't make much sense, unless you say 有名さがほしい (I want famousness), which does not make much sense either. Languages and grammars are meant to serve people's logic, I hope you can also see where this comes from logically.
A while ago I asked a really similar question how to make adjective into imperatives then I realized where my logic went wrong — just like with  "want", an imperative has to be on a verb, never directly the adjective itself. Since you can't DO the adjective, but have to DO the action.

強くなりたい and 有名になりたい are natural, and they're probably good choices for many situations.
Technically, なる means "become". If you really want to say "be", it's possible to use ある, but this isn't as common. There are more details about using adjectives with ある in this question.
Here's a panel from the manga Vagabond that uses both なる and ある. The translation would be something like "I want to be strong. Not become strong; be strong."


I have a feeling the OP does not know what the difference between 強くなりたい and 強くなってほしい would be, and this answer might give the impression they mean the same thing

Oh I see, they're not asking about てほしい. I didn't read the question closely enough. I'll get rid of that.

The assumption about OP was totally correct^^ I have not yet encountered てほしい but I'll read up on it. btw: thanks for the Vagabond panel, it could hardly be more fitting.

"I want to be (become, as in you aren't right now) strong":

強くなりたい

"I want to be (become) famous":

有名になりたい

